# How can I make before-after slider a background

Tags: html, css

I bought before-after jQuery plugin, and I made a simple WordPress-theme. But few things don't work. I wanted to make this slider as my background so I made div in which slider is fit to page, but it doesn't fit. That is my first problem.

My second problem is that gravity forms make some strange things, they are blocking some functions, but I'll fix that.

Here is code:

css:

```
html {
width: 100%;
}

body {
background-color:#A6B8CC;
margin: 0px!important;
}
.titlelogo {
background-image:url(../images/sitelogo.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding-top:35px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:-5px;
display:block;
width:250px;
height:98px;
}
#big_divider {
margin-top:150px;
}

#example{
margin:  auto;
padding: 0px!important;
}

#example img {
max-width: 100vw;
max-height: 100vh;
}

#after {
max-height: 100vh;      
max-width: 100vw;
}

ul {
margin:0px!important;
}

#secondary {
display: none;
}

ul, menu, dir {
display: block;
list-style-type: disc;
-webkit-margin-before: 0em!important;
-webkit-margin-after: 0em!important;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px!important;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px!important;
-webkit-padding-start: 0px!important;
}

#ext_ext_after {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="example" class="beforeafter_slider shadow1">

            <ul>            

                <!-- THE 1. SLIDE -->
                <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/extralightgethaldus2.jpg" alt="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/withglassesgethaldus2.jpg">
                        <div id="textbox_1" class="before">
                            <div id="title_1b" class="fadeup">BEFORE</div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="textbox_1" class="after">
                            <div id="title_1b" class="fadeup">AFTER</div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="textbox_snw">

                            <div id="title" class="fadeup">Don't let the sun be your enemy!</div>
                            <div id="title2" class="fadeup">Do you consider yourself unique?<br>Your glasses should be as well.</div>

                            <div id="description" class="fadeup">We are soon lounching a new eyeware webshop<br>like you've never seen before across all Europe.<br><br>
                                                                Right now we cannot say anithing else, but if you want<br> to be among the firs to be noticed what it's all about<br>
                                                                leave your e-mail adress below and join our community.</div>    
                        </div>
                </li>
            </ul>


        </div>
```

And here is link: http://svinaweb.hr/gethaldus-lp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div will not always fit everyone's screen so to overcome this problem it might be a good idea to change your CSS style to this one below...

```
#example img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Please comment back if you need more help or this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had to change it a bit, because my overlay img is in another div (generated by script), so with 100% it shrinkes when moving horisontal line, so I altered it to 100vw. But overflow hidden solves the problem. It was a rooky mistake, sorry.
But thanks, you helped so much.